# Is there a mini-laptop I can buy?

Tags: laptop, mini-pc

I am looking for a small laptop to match my [RCA Voyager Pro](https://shop.rcaav.com/shop/computing/tablets/rca-voyager-pro-7-16gb-tablet-keyboard-case-android-8-rct6873w42kccf9/). For me, this is a matter of character and style. I want something with decent specifications that I can fit in my pocket (see table below):

```
+-------------+----------------+
| Screen      | Under 9"       |
| RAM         | 8GB+           |
| SSD         | 300GB+         |
| Processor   | Intel Core i3+ |
+-------------+----------------+
```

I came across something called the [One Netbook One Mix 3S Yoga](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T4719T2), which seemed to be exactly what I was looking for. However, after reading the customer reviews, I realized that this laptop has a problem with overheating.

This was the only the only pocket-sized laptop I could find the internet. Is there a different one I may have overlooked?

Comment: Have you looked at anything that is RPi4 based?  Just add a small HDMI LCD screen, and keyboard with mouse pointer https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15447  Maybe more here? https://www.linuxlinks.com/raspberry-pi-4-chronicling-desktop-experience-emulate-home-computers/

Comment: GPD P2 max https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/gpd-p2-max-the-world-s-smallest-ultrabook#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GPD** is THE brand for such toys.

But your list of requirements I think isn't realistic (and in a way not even relevant.) Even normal big laptops don't usually match those specs so why would you look for them in a miny device and then expect it shouldn't even be overly hot... (And TBH, comparing to the RCA Voyager Pro which has 1 GB RAM why are you looking for 16 GB?....)

If you do consider going with **GPD**, there is the 8.9" **[GPD P2 Max](https://amzn.to/2TMqXdN)** and its smaller brother the 7" **[GPD Pocket 2](https://amzn.to/3aS5WUI)**

Comment: I really like the look of the GPD Pocket 2, but a Celeron or m3 processor just wont make the cut. I wish they could put at least an i3 in there. I would not mind a loud fan... ;n;

Comment: Have you looked at the actual specs of these CPUs, or just judging them by name? A core m3-8100Y matches the requirements you had initially. 2 Cores, 4 Threads, single-core turbo 3.4GHz. I3 of the same gen are not much better, especially when crammed into the low TDP envelope of such a small device. Cooling 15W without thermal throttling is not going to happen in this form factor.